# Running an external website written in AngularJS inside a Lightning component, is that possible for them to communicate?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

Is it possible for bi-directional communication (passing parameters either through the URL or via JS methods) to happen for an AngularJS page that is made publicly available, that sits within an iframe or container within LEX? I've been doing some reading but it's not clear to me whether the LockerService is a showstopper. What is available as well, only one-way (from LEX to iframe, or vice-versa) or not at all. Quite new to this, help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios

**Communicate with External Frameworks from Lightning:**

This is very much possible and can easily be achieved by using a [lightning-container](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/04/lightning-container-component-building-components-with-react-angular-and-other-libraries.html)

Lightning-container is a dependency that should be installed

```
npm install lightning-container --save
```

The installed module can be imported for use later

```
import LCC from 'lightning-container';
```

**Communicate with Lightning from External Frameworks:**

This is also possible with [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm). Also, it should be noted about lightning:out approach

> This approach is quite different from embedding an app using an
>   iframe. Aura components running via Lightning Out are full citizens on
>   the page. If you choose to, you can enable interaction between your
>   Lightning components app and the page or app you’ve embedded it in.
>   This interaction is handled using Lightning events.

To Include Lightning out on the page script should be included as:

```
<script src="https://myDomain.my.salesforce.com/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijith. Still not clear to me unfortunately. If I use Lightning:container - isn't it that the AngularJS app needs to be in Static Resources? I am wanting an actual external webpage written using AngularJS but hosted in a remote server.

Comment: Its definitely possible to use an iframe inside the lightning component  .lightning:container does an iframe of the third party application inside the lightning component . if there are http and https urls are mixed you will get a mixed content error so to avoid it always use src value as an https URL .

Comment: Now url Params can be used for the component to pass data to the angular app but vice versa can be tricky to achieve... iframe sample https://github.com/nikitakarpenkov/iframe-lightning-component